# Why does Starcraft II show no maps in Single Player?

Tags: starcraft-2

After reformatting my laptop and reinstalling StarCraft II so I am no longer able to play vs the AI as it shows "No Content Found".

Anyone know how to fix this? Blizzard tech support isn't responding to my ticket.

Comment: Have you logged in to Battle.net since the reinstall?

Comment: @Inzanik is it possible to not log-in to BNet and play SC2??

Comment: @Bora - yes. Though you will be limited to the campaign and singleplayer custom maps (I think)

Comment: Yes, but you need to login to battle.net once to verify your account, then Offline mode should work properly. I think you have to repeat this process every so often.

Comment: Try to stay in the game for a while, for example you can play the campaign, sometimes it takes time to download the maps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After talking to blizzard tech support they suggested I check out my router and no doubt that fixed it... Had a firewall blocking my requests.

Answer (score 3):

Try running the Starcraft 2 repair utility - it can be found under the *"Starcraft II"* folder in your start-menu.

Comment: didnt work =\...